# Filter by rows and sum column values

Tags: r, dplyr, plyr, rowsum

My data looks like

```
pos year A   B
1   2012 1   1
1   2013 1   NA
2   2012 NA  NA
2   2013 NA  1
```

I tried to calculate the percentage difference between A and B for each pos only when both A and B are not NA.

```
ddply(x, .(pos), summarize, diff = ifelse(is.na(A)==FALSE & is.na(B)==FALSE, 
                                      (rowsum(A, pos, na.rm=TRUE)-rowsum(B, pos, na.rm=TRUE))/rowsum(A, pos, na.rm=TRUE),""))
```

So the results should be

```
pos diff
1   0.5
2   NA
```

I don't which part is wrong, but my code produces

```
pos diff
1   0.5
1     
2     
2
```

Any ideas would be appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: Is this what you want `'d %>% 
  filter(!(is.na(A) & is.na(B))) %>% 
  group_by(pos) %>% 
  mutate(A1=sum(A,na.rm = T), A2=sum(B, na.rm = T)) %>% 
  mutate(Dif=A1-A2,
         res=Dif/A1)`

Comment: Hi. Thanks for the filter part. But the rowsum function works well for my case.

Answer (score 0):

Not the most elegant code but it seems to work:

```
df <- data.frame(pos = rep(1:2, each = 2), year = rep(2012:2013, 2),
                 A = rep(c(1, NA), each = 2), B = c(1, NA, NA, 1))

foo <- function(x) ifelse(
  all(is.na(x[[1]])) | all(is.na(x[[2]])),
  NA, (sum(x[[1]], na.rm = T) - sum(x[[2]], na.rm = T)) / nrow(x))
x <- by(df[ , 3:4], df$pos, foo)
data.frame(pos = unique(df$pos), diff = as.vector(x))

   pos diff
    1  0.5
    2   NA
```